# PHP 5.2 Error with static var: "syntax error, unexpected T_STATIC"

Tags: php, variables, static

I have a pretty weird problem:

My Class looks like this

```
<?php
class asd {
    private static $variable;

    public static function blabla(){
        self::$variable="blubb";
    }
}
?>
```

When I'm trying to call asd::blabla() with the help of the __autoload function, everything works fine. 
But when I'm trying to call it without autoload, using include/require I get this, right after the including

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STATIC, expecting T_OLD_FUNCTION or T_FUNCTION or T_VAR or '}' in path/asd.php on line 3

I don't get why it works one way and not the other. I'm not able to use the autoload mechanism in every class, so just using this isn't an option.

e:
Additional info: The file where I want to include the Class is a .rdf file, which gets php parsed via the "AddType application/x-httpd-php .rdf" .htaccess entry.

If I try to include the class it in a random .php file it works perfectly fine, even with a manual include...
This doesn't make sense at all.

e: more info:
If I copy/paste the whole .rdf code into a .php file, everything works. If I now try to include the .php file in the .rdf file the Error arises again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a guess: have you tried this? Notice the 5 at the end of the MIME type. I would think there's a PHP 4 installation on your server that's being run instead of your PHP 5.2 installation when you use the MIME type without the 5.

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php5 .rdf
```

Comment: You're absolutely right! The Script was using PHP Version 4.4.9 withouth the 5 behind it. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your server is running both php4 and php5, and your file is parsed as php4. 
I would guess that php5 scripts should run through cgi